# Entity Framework Migrations renaming tables and columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I renamed a a couple entities and their navigation properties and generated a new Migration in EF 5. As is usual with renames in EF migrations, by default it was going to drop objects and recreate them. That isn't what I wanted so I pretty much had to build the migration file from scratch.

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.ReportSectionGroups", "Report_Id", "dbo.Reports");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.ReportSections", "Group_Id", "dbo.ReportSectionGroups");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Editables", "Section_Id", "dbo.ReportSections");
        DropIndex("dbo.ReportSectionGroups", new[] { "Report_Id" });
        DropIndex("dbo.ReportSections", new[] { "Group_Id" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Editables", new[] { "Section_Id" });

        RenameTable("dbo.ReportSections", "dbo.ReportPages");
        RenameTable("dbo.ReportSectionGroups", "dbo.ReportSections");
        RenameColumn("dbo.ReportPages", "Group_Id", "Section_Id");

        AddForeignKey("dbo.ReportSections", "Report_Id", "dbo.Reports", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.ReportPages", "Section_Id", "dbo.ReportSections", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Editables", "Page_Id", "dbo.ReportPages", "Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.ReportSections", "Report_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.ReportPages", "Section_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Editables", "Page_Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Editables", "Page_Id");
        DropIndex("dbo.ReportPages", "Section_Id");
        DropIndex("dbo.ReportSections", "Report_Id");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Editables", "Page_Id", "dbo.ReportPages");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.ReportPages", "Section_Id", "dbo.ReportSections");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.ReportSections", "Report_Id", "dbo.Reports");

        RenameColumn("dbo.ReportPages", "Section_Id", "Group_Id");
        RenameTable("dbo.ReportSections", "dbo.ReportSectionGroups");
        RenameTable("dbo.ReportPages", "dbo.ReportSections");

        CreateIndex("dbo.Editables", "Section_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.ReportSections", "Group_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.ReportSectionGroups", "Report_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Editables", "Section_Id", "dbo.ReportSections", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.ReportSections", "Group_Id", "dbo.ReportSectionGroups", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.ReportSectionGroups", "Report_Id", "dbo.Reports", "Id");
    }
```

All I'm trying to do is rename `dbo.ReportSections` to `dbo.ReportPages` and then `dbo.ReportSectionGroups` to `dbo.ReportSections`. Then I need to rename the foreign key column on `dbo.ReportPages` from `Group_Id` to `Section_Id`.

I am dropping the foreign keys and indexes linking the tables together, then I am renaming the tables and the foreign key column, then I'm adding the indexes and foreign keys again. I assumed this was going to work but I am getting a SQL error.

> Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 215
>   Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
>   Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Cannot find the object "dbo.ReportSections" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

I'm not having an easy time figuring out what is wrong here. Any insight would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: Which of the above lines fails? Can you trace the migration in SQL Server Profiler and check the corresponding SQL?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Nevermind. I was making this way more complicated than it really needed to be.

This was all that I needed. The rename methods just generate a call to the [sp_rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql) system stored procedure and I guess that took care of everything, including the foreign keys with the new column name.

```
public override void Up()
{
    RenameTable("ReportSections", "ReportPages");
    RenameTable("ReportSectionGroups", "ReportSections");
    RenameColumn("ReportPages", "Group_Id", "Section_Id");
}

public override void Down()
{
    RenameColumn("ReportPages", "Section_Id", "Group_Id");
    RenameTable("ReportSections", "ReportSectionGroups");
    RenameTable("ReportPages", "ReportSections");
}
```

Comment: Be careful with table names which have dots in them. `RenameColumn` generates a `sp_rename` T-SQL statement which uses uses `parsename` internally which has some limitations. So if you have a table name which has dots in it e.g. "SubSystemA.Tablename" then use: `RenameColumn("dbo.[SubSystemA.Tablename]", "OldColumnName", "NewColumnName");`

Comment: This seems to update the columns referenced in the Foreign Keys, but it does not rename the FK itself. Which is a shame, but probably not the end of the world unless you absolutely need to refer to a FK later by its name.

Comment: @mikesigs you can use `RenameIndex(..)` in your migration to rename it

Comment: I am getting an exception when renaming column.  probably because the rename table is still not applied.  I had to divide it into two migrations

Comment: With EF6, use `RenameTable(..)` to rename the FK's and PK's. Doesn't sound right but it's what worked for me. It's the method that creates the correct T-SQL (`execute sp_rename ...`). If you do update-database -verbose, you'll see it for yourself.

Comment: That's great, except `RenameTable` and `RenameColumn` are undefined in Entity Framework Core.

Comment: @JonathanWood [RenameTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.renametable) and [RenameColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.renamecolumn) in EF Core, and the documentation says these are there since EF core 1.0.Not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: I know this thread is for EF, but if you are using EF Core, I found this one really helpful (see the link below). If you use [Table] data annotation entity framework will take care of renaming the tables and indexes. I'm not sure it will work for EF6 (the classic one). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534503/entity-framework-core-2-1-rename-table-using-code-first-migrations-without-drop

Answer (score 77):

If you don't like writing/changing the required code in the Migration class manually, you can follow a two-step approach which automatically make the `RenameColumn` code which is required:

**Step One** Use the `ColumnAttribute` to introduce the new column name and then add-migration (e.g. `Add-Migration ColumnChanged`)

```
public class ReportPages
{
    [Column("Section_Id")]                 //Section_Id
    public int Group_Id{get;set}
}
```

**Step-Two** change the property name and again apply to same migration (e.g. `Add-Migration ColumnChanged -force`) in the Package Manager Console

```
public class ReportPages
{
    [Column("Section_Id")]                 //Section_Id
    public int Section_Id{get;set}
}
```

If you look at the Migration class you can see the automatically code generated is `RenameColumn`.

Comment: How are you able to add the same migration twice? When I try this, I get: `The name 'Rename_SalesArea' is used by an existing migration.`

Comment: have a look at `-force` parameter when using add-migration

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet indicates that the `--force` parameter can only be applied to removing migrations. (`Add-Migration` is equivalent to `dotnet ef migrations add`)

Comment: have a look at the link you provide, It also Overwrite existing files.

Comment: also pay attention this post is not for EF core

Comment: I think you only need one migration, but still two steps.  1. Add attribute and create "rename migration" 2. Just change the property name.  That's it. Either way, this just saved me a ton of time.  Thanks!

Comment: And then you can remove the Column attribute to keep the code clean.

Comment: Okay, you can do this manually in console. But when you deploy these migrations using an automated tool, it's not going to compile twice for applying two migrations. It just gets the latest model and apply both migrations.

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned here and it was successful. I didn't lose any existing data. that what I really wanted, make the changes without losing the data.
But I run the different migration after renaming the property name of the class, for the safe side.

Comment: This was definitely helpful. Adding [Column("NewName")] caused the migration to do a rename. Later when I renamed the property, the migration had nothing to do (which is good). Then after that I removed the [Column("NewName")], and the migration still have nothing to do (which is great).

Comment: If you want to use this method for EF Core, definitely do the two steps with two separate migrations: ColumnChanged_A, then ColumnChanged_B. If you don't you risk having your DBModelSnapshot reference the old Property name. (maybe this will always sort itself in later migrations, but still seems kinda risky)

Answer (score 62):

In EF Core, I use the following statements to rename tables and columns:

As for renaming tables:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "OldTableName",
            schema: "dbo",
            newName: "NewTableName",
            newSchema: "dbo");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "NewTableName",
            schema: "dbo",
            newName: "OldTableName",
            newSchema: "dbo");
    }
```

As for renaming columns:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "OldColumnName",
            table: "TableName",
            newName: "NewColumnName",
            schema: "dbo");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "NewColumnName",
            table: "TableName",
            newName: "OldColumnName",
            schema: "dbo");
    }
```

Answer (score 33):

To expand a bit on Hossein Narimani Rad's answer, you can rename both a table and columns using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute respectively.

This has a couple benefits:

1. Not only will this create the the name migrations automatically, but
2. it will also deliciously delete any foreign keys and recreate them against the new table and column names, giving the foreign keys and constaints proper names.
3. All this without losing any table data

For example, adding `[Table("Staffs")]`:

```
[Table("Staffs")]
public class AccountUser
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long AccountId { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Will generate the migration:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AccountUsers_Accounts_AccountId",
            table: "AccountUsers");

        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AccountUsers_AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId",
            table: "AccountUsers");

        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_AccountUsers",
            table: "AccountUsers");

        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "AccountUsers",
            newName: "Staffs");

        migrationBuilder.RenameIndex(
            name: "IX_AccountUsers_ApplicationUserId",
            table: "Staffs",
            newName: "IX_Staffs_ApplicationUserId");

        migrationBuilder.RenameIndex(
            name: "IX_AccountUsers_AccountId",
            table: "Staffs",
            newName: "IX_Staffs_AccountId");

        migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_Staffs",
            table: "Staffs",
            column: "Id");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Staffs_Accounts_AccountId",
            table: "Staffs",
            column: "AccountId",
            principalTable: "Accounts",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Staffs_AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId",
            table: "Staffs",
            column: "ApplicationUserId",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Staffs_Accounts_AccountId",
            table: "Staffs");

        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Staffs_AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId",
            table: "Staffs");

        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_Staffs",
            table: "Staffs");

        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "Staffs",
            newName: "AccountUsers");

        migrationBuilder.RenameIndex(
            name: "IX_Staffs_ApplicationUserId",
            table: "AccountUsers",
            newName: "IX_AccountUsers_ApplicationUserId");

        migrationBuilder.RenameIndex(
            name: "IX_Staffs_AccountId",
            table: "AccountUsers",
            newName: "IX_AccountUsers_AccountId");

        migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_AccountUsers",
            table: "AccountUsers",
            column: "Id");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AccountUsers_Accounts_AccountId",
            table: "AccountUsers",
            column: "AccountId",
            principalTable: "Accounts",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AccountUsers_AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId",
            table: "AccountUsers",
            column: "ApplicationUserId",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }
```

Comment: Seems like it should be the default to add the table attribute, makes things so much simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also just wanted to point out that after the first migration, you will typically remove the attribute and rename the table. **It is very important to run one more migration at this point** - you can name it "TempMigration" and then delete the actual migration afterwards, but it's important that the context snapshot gets updated with the new class name.

Comment: @Groo, when I run the second migration after renaming the actual properties I see a drop table and stuff like that in the new migration script. You're saying that we can just discard that migration, and keep the snapshot, correct?

Comment: @Emulic: no, usually you shouldn't be getting any drop statements. So when you remove the attributes and rename the columns after the first migration, the next migration's `Up` and `Down` methods should be empty, just the snapshot file should be updated. Perhaps you need to check if all spelling is ok?

Comment: @groo, thank you. Yeah, I realized I made a mistake with missing the plural s on the entity rename in step 1. After I fixed that after I created the migration at the end it was actually empty. Thanks on all the great info.

Comment: I would suggest also checking out this answer that mentions renaming foreign key references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802766/103836

Comment: This example only shows a table rename... does it work with table + column rename?

Comment: This worked just fine to rename the existing table. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

In ef core, you can change the migration that was created after add migration. And then do update-database. A sample has given below:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(name: "Type", table: "Users", newName: "Discriminator", schema: "dbo");
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{            
    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(name: "Discriminator", table: "Users", newName: "Type", schema: "dbo");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For EF Core `migrationBuilder.RenameColumn` usually works fine but sometimes you have to handle indexes as well.

```
migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(name: "Identifier", table: "Questions", newName: "ChangedIdentifier", schema: "dbo");
```

Example error message when updating database:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The index
> 'IX_Questions_Identifier' is dependent on column 'Identifier'.
>
> The index 'IX_Questions_Identifier' is dependent on column 'Identifier'.
>
> RENAME COLUMN Identifier failed because one or more objects access
> this column.

In this case you have to do the rename like this:

```
migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
    name: "IX_Questions_Identifier",
    table: "Questions");

migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(name: "Identifier", table: "Questions", newName: "ChangedIdentifier", schema: "dbo");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Questions_ChangedIdentifier",
    table: "Questions",
    column: "ChangedIdentifier",
    unique: true,
    filter: "[ChangedIdentifier] IS NOT NULL");
```

Answer (score 3):

[Hossein Narimani Rad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13297248/9545326) answer is really nice and straightforward. But it doesn't work for the EF core. because `dotnet ef migration add` doesn't have the `--force` option.

You have to do it this way.

1- add `[Column("NewColumnName")]`

2- create a migration `dotnet ef migration add RenameSomeColumn`

3- copy all the code in `RenameSomeColumn.cs`

4- remove migration `dotnet ef migrations remove`

5- remove `[Column("NewColumnName")]` and rename Property to `NewColumnName`

6- again create migration `dotnet ef migration add RenameSomeColumn`

7- past all the code copied from removed migration into new `RenameSomeColumn.cs`

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the same in EF6 (code first entity rename). I simply renamed the class and added a migration using the package manager console and voila, a migration using RenameTable(...) was automatically generated for me. I have to admit that I made sure the only change to the entity was renaming it so no new columns or renamed columns so I cannot be certain if this is an EF6 thing or just that EF was (always) able to detect such simple migrations.

Comment: I can confirm this with 6.1.3 It does correctly rename the table (don't forget to rename the `DbSet` in your `DatabaseContext` as well). Changing the primary key does cause trouble. The migration will try to delete it and create a new one. So you need to adjust that and do as Chev's answer is, rename the column.

Answer (score 2):

Table names and column names can be specified as part of the mapping of `DbContext`. Then there is no need to do it in migrations.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Cuisines)
            .WithMany(r => r.Restaurants)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("RestaurantId");
                mc.MapRightKey("CuisineId");
                mc.ToTable("RestaurantCuisines");
            });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was happening with me because I set `builder.ToTable("hardCodedTableName");` in my table configuration file. When you use this **ToTable** method EF overrides the name chosen in the DbSet. That's why my tables were never renamed (because they still had this hardcoded old name). Very stupid, but maybe it was the case of others as well..