# Table deleted from database, how to re-create it by migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations

In my MVC Web App, I've added a model called **Competencies** to the existing models, and did `add-migration` and `update-database`, it worked fine, and then I've created a controller based on that model, it was OK.

But after that, I've realized that something was wrong, so I've deleted the controller and its views with the model. I also have deleted the table from Server Explorer, and have created a new model called **CompetencyLabel**, and run `add-migration`, it works fine, but when I run `update-database`, I got this error in PM> window:

> "Cannot find the object "dbo.Competencies" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

That table has been deleted and I do not know why it still asks me that. Does anybody know how to make it working? thanks a lot.

Comment: by "run update-database" do you mean when updating your edmx?

Comment: This is asp.net MVC web apps, and I am using EF code first, so when model changes everytime, I have to run that code in Package Management Consol (PM), please let me know if you more question, thanks

Comment: Try creating a dummy Competencies tables in SQL, then run update-database, giving the PMC a chance to delete the table..    Also, add  -verbose to your update-database command to see what it is attempting to do to the Competencies table

Comment: Try that, but still not work, as original model has " public virtual PerfPlan PerfPlan { get; set; }" , so I do not knwo how to apply this in the dummy table, when I use update-database -verbose, I got new error:  'FK_dbo.Competencies_dbo.PerfPlans_PerfPlanID' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: after I added PerfPlanID to the table, I got this error: 'PK_dbo.Competencies' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: any idea how to resolve this issue? thanks

Answer (score 19):

When you get this error, try to arrange your `Up()` statements in order. For example,
[image: Before Rearrangement]

When you look at the image above, you realize that, the `Users` table is renamed in the beginning and on the next line, a SQL statement is generated to drop a foreign key in the `Users` table but to Entity Framework, that table (that is the `Users` table) doesn't exist anymore so it will throw an error.

Rearrange the statements so that when the `Users` table is renamed, it is not called again. An example is seen in the image below.
[image: After Rearrangement]

Comment: Why does EF do that though? I never told it to rename the tables that way, and it still tries to do it and messes up the migration!

Answer (score 13):

When you enter `Enable-Migrations` command, a `Migrations` folder is created in the project. Whenever you `Add-Migration`, a new migration file is created in that folder. In the file, there are two methods defined:

- `Up()` - defines actions to take, when we are upgrading the database using `Update-Database`
- `Down()` - defines actions to take when we are downgrading the database using `Update-Database`

As you have deleted Competencies model, the latest migration added code to the `Up()` method, which destroys indexes on Competencies table and drops the table. As you have done it manually, just remove the code responsible for it and `Update-Database`. It should upgrade it without problems.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you have redone the migrations of your project, EF will still remember schema changes.

We had a similar problem early in a project and we fixed it by removing the _MigrationHistory table from the database and then regenerated the migrations.

Answer (score 4):

I found another answer for this problem.

My scenario was that I made changes in my entities (change relations and entitites names). When i ran the `update-database -verbose` I found that it was running some functions with the "EntityHistory" but that entity didnt exist anymore because I changed the name of it to "AnotherEntityHistory". Then, as result I get the "*Cannot find the object "dbo.EntityHistory" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions*".

What I did was rename the AnotherEntityHistory to EntityHistory again, run the Update-database (everything will be ok because it now has the "missing" entity EntityHistory) , rename again the EntityHistory  to AnotherEntityHistory  and run update-database again.

You will see that now it only has to rename the table instead of renaming tables, drop indexes, etc....

In this way you dont have to remove any table or the migration values.

Answer (score 2):

As you have deleted / modified the database contents manually after applying the `Add-Migration`  and before doing `Update-Database` (*I guess Error is generated here*)

- Delete corresponding migration file from Migration Folder as its not applied correctly
  revert the previous migration using `Update-Database –TargetMigration: OldMigration` or delete the generated db or need to clear old migration record from database table
- Apply the migration `Add-Migration` from NPM code first migration
- Perform the database update from `Add-Migration` command

This resolves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

remove all migration classes that you have added manually in Migrations folder (by add-migration command) type this command `add-migration MigrationName -ProjectName YourProjectName`

if every thing works fine you should see the following code in Up method of newly created migration class

`DropTable("dbo.Competencies");
 CreateTable("dbo.CompetencyLabel");`

then run this command `update-database -verbose -ProjectName YourProjectName`

happy coding

Answer (score 2):

My problem was similar to the one described in [@EduLopez' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31725786/109941).

1. Much like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13297248/109941) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739716/109941), I manually modified a migration. Specifically, I wanted to rename a table (rather than drop and create a table).
2. And my code was as such:

   ```
       protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
       {    
           migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
               name: "oldTableName",
               schema: "oldSchemaName",
               newName: "newTableName"                    
           );
       }
   ```

---

**Solution:** Just like [@EduLopez suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31725786/109941), I ran `update-database -verbose` and discovered that I needed to specify the **new schema name**:

```
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {    
            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "oldTableName",
                schema: "oldSchemaName",
                newName: "newTableName",
                newSchema: "newSchemaName" // added this line
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write dbo.xxx.dbo.yyy where xxx is the database name and yyy is the table name. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First let me to tell **reason** of this error:

You delete migration manually and after that you think its enough.But in new migration that you create its effect is exist.

**Solution:**

Open all migration one by one and remove parts that indicate to `dbo-xxxx`

just it:)