# Rename a foreign key in Entity Framework Core without dropping data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have two model classes:

```
public class Survey
{
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    public Survey Survey { get; set; }
}
```

I want to rename `Survey` to `StudentSurvey`, so it will have `StudentSurveyId`. I update the class name and the properties in the models accordingly and add a migration.

However, I get:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_User_Surveys_SurveyId". The conflict occurred in database "AppName", table "dbo.Survey", column 'SurveyId'.

I think it is trying to drop the data and because it requires data in the column (cannot be null) I'm seeing that error. But I don't want to drop the data. How can I just rename it?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

EF Core treats the entity class rename as deleting the old entity and adding a new entity, hence generates a migration to drop the original table and create a new one.

The workaround requires the following steps:

(1) Before renaming the entity, "rename" the table and the PK column by using either `ToTable` and `HasColumnName` fluent API or data annotations. Also do the same for FK columns referencing the entity.

For instance:

```
[Table("StudentSurveys")]
public class Survey
{
    [Column("StudentSurveyId")]
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Column("StudentSurveyId")]
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    public Survey Survey { get; set; }
}
```

(2) Add new migration. It will correctly rename the table, PK column, FK columns and the associated constraints:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Users_Surveys_SurveyId",
        table: "Users");

    migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
        name: "PK_Surveys",
        table: "Surveys");

    migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
        name: "Surveys",
        newName: "StudentSurveys");

    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
        name: "SurveyId",
        table: "Users",
        newName: "StudentSurveyId");

    migrationBuilder.RenameIndex(
        name: "IX_Users_SurveyId",
        table: "Users",
        newName: "IX_Users_StudentSurveyId");

    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
        name: "SurveyId",
        table: "StudentSurveys",
        newName: "StudentSurveyId");

    migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
        name: "PK_StudentSurveys",
        table: "StudentSurveys",
        column: "StudentSurveyId");

    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Users_StudentSurveys_StudentSurveyId",
        table: "Users",
        column: "StudentSurveyId",
        principalTable: "StudentSurveys",
        principalColumn: "StudentSurveyId",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
}
```

(3) Remove the annotations / fluent configuration and do the actual class/property rename:

```
public class StudentSurvey
{
    public int StudentSurveyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int SurveyUserId { get; set; }
    public int StudentSurveyId { get; set; }
    public StudentSurvey StudentSurvey { get; set; }
}
```

rename the corresponding `DbSet` if any:

```
public DbSet<StudentSurvey> StudentSurveys { get; set; }
```

and you are done.

You can verify that by adding a new migration - it will have empty `Up` and `Down` methods.

Comment: It's as though I need to add `[Column("StudentSurveyId")]` above every model that has a `SurveyId` foreign key in. I will try that...

Comment: That worked. I then applied rename refactoring (resharper) to get Survey changed to StudentSurvey in my project. And then your step 3 didn't work; drop and create statements showed in my migration code. I had forgotten to change my context: `public DbSet<StudentSurvey> Surveys { get; set; }` needed to become `public DbSet<StudentSurvey> StudentSurveys { get; set; }` then I hit the same problem. Because StudentSurveys needed to be StudentSurvey. In hindsight I should have pluralised the the `[Table(StudentSurvey)]` in my first annotation. I'd recommend updating your answer to consider all this.

Comment: Ok. At least it was a good starting point :) In my test, I didn't rename the FK column. And was assuming the `DbSet` rename is part of the "rename" operation. Anyway, the answer is updated now, did I miss something?

Comment: @PateeGutee Unfortunately seems like this doesn't work for EF6.

Comment: In EF core 3: If I do not generate second (empty) migration then I have still in ModelSnapshot: b.Property<string>("Old")
                        .HasColumnName("New")

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#column-renames) suggests using `MigrationBuilder.RenameColumn()`.  There is also `RenameIndex()`, `RenameTable()` and a stored procedure '[sp_rename](https://database.guide/rename-a-foreign-key-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/)' (in SQL Server) **for renaming foreign keys**.  E.g:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql($"EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.{oldName}', '{newName}'");
```

Use the database scripting tool in SQL Server Management Studio (*rt-click on DB | Tasks | Generate Scripts...*) to generate schema scripts, **with and without EF migration customizations**, that can be compared.  Then you'll know the EF naming is preserved.

**EDIT:** Added 'EXEC ...' to support generation of standalone T-SQL scripts